# Can I use node.js as a REPL shell?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

This is a noob question.

I am trying to use `node.js` as a `JavaScript` REPL (read-evaluate-print loop) shell to work with JavaScript interactively. Unfortunately I can define neither variables nor functions.

```
> var x = 'abc'
undefined
> function f() {}
undefined
>
```

What can I do to use `node.js` as a REPL shell?

P.S. I know I can probably use [Rhino Shell](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell) but I would prefer `node`.

Comment: and you would prefer node, because... ?

Comment: Probably because of the nicer output when printing e.g. objects.

Comment: @HansWesterbeek I would prefer `node` because it's a "native" application and it takes less time to start it as opposed to `java`.

Comment: well at least rhino can use multiple cores :)

Comment: Hans I am suprised at you, your answers are good, this is a good question, not the place for node/rhino war

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* do so. However, those expressions do not have a return value so node prints `undefined`.

```
> var x = 'abc'
undefined
> function f() {}
undefined
> f
[Function: f]
> x
'abc'
>
```

Comment: if you want to avoid the undefined do something like **v1={};v1.v=12**